# Android: как сделать список из Nexus Clock?

Tags: expandablelistview, android, java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такой список:

[image]

Поиски по гуглу и `StackOverflow` результата не принесли, в основном попадаются только обзоры по тому, что изменилось в `Nexus5` относительно старых версий.

`P.S.:` будет ли корректно отображаться такой список в более ранних версиях `Android` `(4.0.3-4.0.4, 4.1.х, 4.2.х, 4.3)`?

**Обновление**

1. Как сделать уползающую вниз стрелку (у дефолтного `ExpandabledList` она остается сверху)?
2. Как повесить анимацию раздвижения (не знаю, видели ли вы этот список на `Nexus5`)?
3. Как убрать линии у дочерних элементов списка?
4. Как организован дочерний элемент списка? Это один элемент или 3 отдельные строки (1 - "Повторить", 2 - "дни недели", 3- "рингтон и вибросигнал")

Это всё конечно по крупицам можно найти, но если есть готовое решение, на внедрение которого потребуется гораздо меньше времени, зачем изобретать велосипед?

`UPD:` работать будет на всех версиях 4.х ([`Kitkat Clock`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxlogix.clock))

Comment: Так а в чём сложность то? И причём тут нексус и версия андроид?

Comment: @Чад - начал разбирать APK этих часов, оказалось что это не `ExpandabledList`, а обычный `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте лайоут для отображение открытый, закрытый, повести анимацию на открытие, закрытие, инфлатером наполняйте. Если хотите чтобы на всех системах - пишите свой компонент, стандартный может варьироватся даже от девайса к девайса на одной и той же версии.